# Warning: <BigQueryConnection> uses an old dbplyr interface

Tags: r, dbi, dbplyr, bigrquery, dbconnect

I'm trying to suppress the following warning

```
Warning: <BigQueryConnection> uses an old dbplyr interface
ℹ Please install a newer version of the package or contact the maintainer
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
```

I know the code that produces this warning is

```
result <- DBI::dbConnect(bigrquery::bigquery(),
                           project = project_id,
                           dataset = dataset)
```

I have the most updated versions of both dbplyr = 2.3.2, DBI = 1.1.3, and bigrquery = 1.4.2 (all the most updated versions.)

I haven't tried anything besides double checking that all packages are updated to the most recent versions. Is this warning a bug or what?

Comment: Well ... it would appear that `bigQueryR` does not implement [`dbplyr_edition`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acloudyr%2FbigQueryR%20dbplyr_edition&type=code) as suggested by [`dbplyr::dbplyr_edition`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/984186b6dec4d38a216985126c65391d13796668/R/db.R#L166-L194). Adding to this that `bigQueryR` has not been updated in over 2 years (not always bad), it might be time to submit a bug report to implement/update dbplyr integration.

Comment: The warning appears on the bigrquery [readme example](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/blob/main/README.md) as well, so probably not worth worrying about

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/1359#issuecomment-1719770884),

> The warning is referring entirely to an issue in dbplyr itself. It essentially saying "the developers of dbplyr haven't yet written a backend for JDBC that is up to their own current standards".

This applies beyond JDBC as well. A better warning would be useful.

I haven't checked the roadmap, but the upgrade may be on the timeline.